# Weird Bug or Issue using Timer and ScrollView together

Tags: swift, swiftui

I found out when I am scrolling or refreshing scrollView "I mean scrolling from top to bottom and release" my TimeModel stop working for unknown reason, kind of scrolling on ScrollView freezing everything in app, I like to know have you seeing such a issue, or how could we fix it? thanks to all. also I made a gif that you can see the problem.

[image]

```
 import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var timeModel: TimeModel = TimeModel()
    
    var body: some View {

        ScrollView() {

            ForEach(0...10, id:\.self) { _ in
                
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .bold()
                    .padding()
                
            }
            
        }

        Button("Start Timer") { timeModel.startTimer() }.padding()
        
    }
}


class TimeModel: ObservableObject {
    
   var timer: Timer = Timer()

    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
      }

    @objc private func timerFunction() {
        print("Tik!")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [The ultimate guide to Timer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer):

> Working with runloops
>
> One common problem folks hit when using timers is that they won’t fire
> when the user is interacting with your app. For example, if the user
> has their finger touching the screen so they can scroll through a
> table view, your regular timers won’t get fired.
>
> This happens because we’re implicitly creating our timer on the
> defaultRunLoopMode, which is effectively the main thread of our
> application. This will then get paused while the user is actively
> interacting with our UI, then reactivated when they stop.
>
> The easiest solution is to create the timer without scheduling it
> directly, then add it by hand to a runloop of your choosing. In this
> case, .common is the one we want: it allows our timers to fire even
> when the UI is being used.

A solution is to run your timer on the `RunLoop` in the `common` mode:

```
func startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common) // add this line
}
```